# differences between adding Foreign constraint and without on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

At past, I was used to make a table relationship programmatically, which is quite handy since you don't need to make FK constraint to each table which have relation.

But, I wonder what is the differences or the advantages of giving a FK constraint to tables that have relation, instead of just creating an attribute and retrieve them programmatically (calls the tables where field = another table PK).

Just some information, I work on php independent MVC framework without any dependency to eloquent or something else. 
Hope someone give me some short lesson on this :D Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: FK constraint is better since it watches on relations. It can remove related entities when removing main entity. It can `set null` on kids when removing  a parent. It forbids to insert related entity without existing parent, when you provide not existing `parent_id`

Answer (score 2):

There are certain principles that you should follow while coding and development, I can say that there is no issue whether or not you create a foreign key constraint to a table that has relation or not but you know that won't restrict the column to have only those values that are being referenced by it. So basically it is not a good DB Schema and may lead to inconsistencies. For example deleting a parent table's row you will have to manually delete the child table's row on the other hand if you have a foreign key constraint that to *onDelete = cascade*, your database will automatically take care of everything and there won't any inconsistencies.